# Ugly font on MS Edge

Tags: css, fonts

This is how **Roboto Condensed** font with Polish language characters looks in my website

On Edge - bad
[image]

On Google Chrome - good
[image]

My question is how to fix Polish language characters displaying on MS Edge?

I have full available import of this font by google fonts:

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:400,700&amp;subset=cyrillic,cyrillic-ext,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,vietnamese
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<link href='http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto&subset=latin,greek,greek-ext,latin-ext,cyrillic' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
```

Comment: it still looks same

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.